# ClaimRow() functionality but with SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql

I need to Claim some rows in a data extension, but no mail is sent, so I cant use AMPSCRIPT, is it possible to make same functionality but only with SQL or other available tools within SFMC?

Case:
New subscribers (added though API) need a unique cardID, which I have in a DE.
So I somehow need to merge each subscriber with an cardID, and make use no one else get the same cardID. Any ideas?

Comment: If your new subscriber is being added through API, why not use the API at the same time of processing to retrieve the a CardID from your Data Extension and then flag an 'is claimed' value in the data extension. 

Attempting to do it through SQL would be messy - if you were doing it in SQL, it could only ever be done on batch process . 

You could build a Custom Activity in a journey builder and do it that way too .... but it would be easiest to claim the cardID at time of API submit ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, my first thought was to do it in the API, then i thought maybe it was best to keep all the logic within Salesforce.. but you are right, then it needs to be in batches, which are not so good in this case. (the client dont have journey builder installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your new subscriber is being added through API, then use the API at the same time of processing to retrieve the a CardID from your Data Extension and then flag an 'is claimed' value in the data extension. Attempting to do it through SQL would be messy - if you were doing it in SQL, it could only ever be done on batch process.